# Economical jQuery Code

Tags: jquery

I often end up with chunks of jQuery code that are similar and repeated several times. For instance:

```
$("#showdescription").on("click", function(){
    $('#description_sh').toggleClass("down");
    $("#hiddendescription").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
$("#showrooms").on("click", function(){
        $('#rooms_sh').toggleClass("down");
        $("#hiddenrooms").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
$("#showmeals").on("click", function(){
        $('#meals_sh').toggleClass("down");
        $("#hiddenmeals").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
$("#showout").on("click", function(){
        $('#out_sh').toggleClass("down");
        $("#hiddenout").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
$("#showreviews").on("click", function(){
        $('#reviews_sh').toggleClass("down");
        $("#hiddenreviews").toggleClass("hidden");
  });
```

I've been trying to find a way to roll that together so I could potentially get the code down to not much more than 20% of what there is at the moment. Unfortunately all my efforts to date have just broken the whole thing. I'm feeling stupid today. It must be easy, mustn't it?

Comment: Since this appears to be working code that you want improved, you probably want to post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com rather than here.  Hint: think about creating a function that you pass three strings to.

Comment: Hmm, yes, if that's the most appropriate I'll do that. Oddly, the first obstacle seems to be that it doesn't use the same log-in as Stack Overflow, so maybe I need to register from scratch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to see more of your code to be sure but assuming the classes you're adding all follow the same html structure and are near eachother in the DOM in an identical way.

You could do something like this:

Keep all unique Id's and Classes but add one identical class to each of the clickable elements (#showdescription, #showrooms etc.). Call this class something like "info-container" or whatever you like but just make sure this class is added to each element you wish to run a click function on.

Now assuming the HTML structure is roughly the same for each container, you can use a .each function like this:

```
$('.info-container').each(function (){

});
```

This will target the same classes but individually using the "this" selector inside. So whatever run inside of here will only run on that individual class that's clicked, even though there are multiple classes of the same name.

Inside of here we can now put the click function in using "this" as a selector:

```
$('.info-container').each(function (){
    $(this).click(function () {
        //code here
    });
});
```

now inside this click function, we need to find the elements we want to add the class to. There are multiple ways of doing this but the best way i like is to navigate the DOM tree by using .sibling and .parent methods. Now, make sure the elements that you're going to be adding classes to have the same class name so we can target them. E.g. '.hidden-container'.

```
$('.info-container').each(function (){
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).children('.hidden-container').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

This part is important also: if the html structure is NOT the same for each container, using .siblings or parent wont work as it will return different results. In this case we wont use sibling, children or parent. Instead we will use .find and .closest. .find will find the nearest element with 'x' class name but only descending down the DOM tree. like this:

```
$('.info-container').each(function (){
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).find('.hidden-container').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

.Closest will travel up the DOM, simmilar to .parent. Read the Jquery manual for the differences.

```
$('.info-container').each(function (){
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.hidden-container').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

You can also traverse up and down the DOM by combining .sibling, .closest, .children etc.

```
$('.info-container').each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        $(this).children('classname').siblings('classname').children('classname').addClass('newClass');
    });
});
```

Overall, this is a good method when working with multiple elemnts that do, in theory, the same thing. Make sure they're all structured out the same HTML wise. Make sure they all have non-unique classes so you can target them all instead of individually.

Hope this helps and please feel free to email me: work@jpwebdev.com. I'm working full time as Full Stack Web Dev but always have time to help!

Kind Regards

Jon

Comment: Wow Jon! That's fantastic. I haven't quite got my head around all of it yet, but that looks like my solution. And yes, the HTML does all follow the same pattern so I should be able to use the simpler version of your answer (the one I stand a chance of understanding) and won't need to get in to .closest .thirdcousin and all that. Thanks. Slightly prematurely maybe, I'm going to mark this as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Reusable way without ruin your approach:

```
var eventElements = [{
  target: '#showdescription',
  affected: ['#description_sh', '#hiddendescription']
}, {
  target: '#showrooms',
  affected: ['#rooms_sh', '#hiddenrooms']
}, {
  target: '#showmeals',
  affected: ['#meals_sh', '#hiddenmeals']
}, {
  target: '#showout',
  affected: ['#out_sh', '#hiddenout']
}, {
  target: '#showreviews',
  affected: ['#reviews_sh', '#hiddenreviews']
}];

eventElements.forEach(function (el) {
  $(el.target).on('click', function () {
    $(el.affected[0]).toggleClass("down");
    $(el.affected[1]).toggleClass("hidden");
  });
});
```